# Can i achieve to transferring video data from Mac OS to iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I want to transfer video files from macOS to iOS devices. My objective here is to create a connection between a Mac running OS to a device running iOS, via bluetooth. I know that I might be able to use CoreBluetooth for this but I don't understand how since I don't see a method to setup a service on the MacOS device and broadcast...

Any solution for that?

Comment: You would need an application running on the Mac to communicate with your app running n the iOS device. To transfer files with Bluetooth you probably want to use an L2Cap connection otherwise it will be too slow.  CoreBluetooth is available on both iOS and macOS, so setting up service advertising is basically the same on both platforms.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you very much fro your reply.